# Is there something similar to C# discards in C++

Tags: c++

Take the following piece of code in C#:

```
_ = 10 + 10;
```

Here, `_` means discard, which is used to basically ignore variables not used anywhere. It also shows that the unused expression was intentional by the programmer. Now what I'm wondering is that is there anything like this in C++?

Comment: You can write `10 + 10;` in C++ and it will evaluate the expression and discard it. Can you give a little bit more context on how this is used in practice?

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore variables"?  If you declare a variable and don't use it, an optimizing compiler will more than likely eliminate it from the final executable.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I'm not much of a C# person. What I mean is that `_` shows that (in this case), `10+10` was intentional by the programmer, not just mistakenly left out.

Comment: `10 + 10` is `20`, and that result is discarded.  What is the programmer supposed to do with a discarded value?  I can see if it was `object + object` and `object` has an overloaded `+` that had side-effects.  But for plain `int` types, it is basically a no-op (once an optimizing compiler deals with it).

Comment: Instead of `auto x = DoSomething();` you can just say `DoSomething();` unless the function has the attribute `[[nodiscard]]` which would have the effect of discarding the returned value. You could do the same with the example expression in your original post.

Comment: A cast to `void` is sometimes used in C (maybe C++ too?) to suppress warnings about unused variables, values, etc.  E.g. if `foo` is a function parameter that you don't want to use, then `(void)foo;` will prevent most compilers from warning you about it.  Not sure if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: I guess OP wants to notify people who read the code (or themself) that the return value exists, but was intentionally ignored

Comment: C++ has [`std::ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/ignore).

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov Yeah that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From C++17, you can use [attribute](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused) `maybe_unused` in order to specify to the compiler that you know it could be unused and you don't need the warning. Example:

```
[[maybe_unused]] const int x = foo();
assert(x > 0); // unused when compiled without debug mode
```

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this question while looking for the same thing OP was looking for and I feel that people in the comments are missing the point of C# discards, possibly because of the example given.

In C#, you can use a discard if a function you're calling has several out parameters but you don't need them all. For instance, suppose a third party library has a function that returns the current temperature in fahrenheit and celsius.

```
void GetTemperature(out float temperatureInFahrenheit, out float temperatureInCelsius);
```

Now, if you only need the temperature in Celsius, you could create a fahrenheit variable and ignore it, like so:

```
float fahrenheit;
float celsius;

GetTemperature(out fahrenheit, out celsius);
// Do something with celsius and ignore fahrenheit
```

However, that's going to create compiler warnings about unused variables and it's basically not very clean code. Since C# 7, you can use a discard for this:

```
float celsius;
GetTemperature(_, out celsius);
// Do something with celsius because there is no other variable
```

It's much cleaner and avoids confusion by explicitly declaring the intent to discard the value in that out parameter.

In C++, like Eljay said I guess there's std::ignore that you can use like this, but unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be anything like that in the language itself, which is a shame if you're on a platform where you can't use the Standard Library, like microcontrollers.

Comment: There's nothing to stop you from writing your own `ignore`. And TBH a microcontroller should still implement all the zero-overhead stuff from the standard library like `std::swap` etc, even if they skip `std::fstream` and `std::thread`.